# No supported authentication methods available in PuTTY

Tags: windows-7, linux, ssh, permissions, putty

I need to set up passwordless login from a Windows 7 client today, but am not having a good time.  I used PuTTYgen to [create the private and public key](https://sachinsharm.wordpress.com/2015/05/10/puttygen-putty-ssh-key-generator-for-windows/) on my Windows client.  I selected `SHA-2 RSA` as the key type.

Next I copied the public key generated by PuTTYgen to my CentOS server under `/home/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys`.  I removed the line returns so that the key format looks like keys added from my Linux systems.   I ensured permissions and ownership were correct.

**Note**, I am able to SSH to this same $user from my LinuxMint laptop using passwordless login, so I know the ownership and permissions are correct.

Before my attempted connection in PuTTY from Windows, I've selected the Auto-login username (Connection -> Data), and selected the private key (Connection -> SSH -> Auth).

When I attempt to connect to the server I get:

```
No supported authentication methods available in PuTTY
```

This is confirmed in the server's /var/log/secure file.

```
error: Received disconnect from 1.2.3.4: 14: No supported authentication methods available [preauth]
```

If I temporarily set PasswordAuthentication to yes on the server, I can log in from Windows using standard user/password authentication.

I've also tried running PuTTY as Administrator.  Same error.

Are there additional packages needed in Windows to make passwordless login work from Windows?

Comment: You edited the public key file and removed line returns? that doesn't sound like a correct thing to do. There are different formats of key.. I have mainly used openssh,  you can install that with cygwin. It's worth giving that a go.  You'll have a better idea what's going on 'cos it's command line.. and a GUI for something like ssh can make things less clear. There's a command with openssh  `ssh-copy-id` whereby if you can log in with a password, you can run the command and will copy the key over, so that next time you log in, it goes in automatically.